# SharePoint Enterprise installation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have SharePoint Standard 2013 Server Sp1 setup files, Now in my production environment I want upgrade my license to enterprise. I have already installed SharePoint. Do I need to re-install SharePoint if not can you share the procedure?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to reinstall the SharePoint. Simply update the product key in central admin.

```
Go to Central Admin -> Upgrade& Migration -> Convert farm license type
```

type the Enterprise key and After that you have to enable the enterprise features as well.
http://www.themossblog.com/sharepoint-general/enable-sharepoint-2013-enterprise-features-convert-from-sharepoint-2013-standard-to-sharepoint-2013-enterprise